# Hello world Bluetooth hardware

Tags: bluetooth

I just want to broadcast a simple Bluetooth message to an iPhone, no pairing or bidirectional anything. Do I need a full featured Bluetooth module? Or can I just use a microcontroller and an antenna?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

### **Use a microcontroller with a Bluetooth module.**

In theory, you could use a microcontroller and an antenna along with the communications circuitry, but it will be more expensive and power-hungry than using a Microcontroller with a Bluetooth module. Not to mention the time to develop Bluetooth from scratch.

#### Why would developing custom Bluetooth be more expensive?

The Large Scale Integration of multiple functions on a single chip, coupled with economies of scale will make a microcontroller with Bluetooth integrated (or a discrete Bluetooth module) much cheaper than building Bluetooth transmission using a microcontroller, antenna and discrete components.

#### Why would it be more power hungry?

Integrated circuits with an integrated antenna have lesser area and dissipate less power compared to discrete components.